# How to add data to a new formed column

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am trying to add data to a newly created column...

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet;
ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Count");
Data.DataSource = ds;
Data.DataBind();
```

Where do I add, a hardcoded count? (I want count column to have '4')

Comment: Is this table an Html table or are you trying to just have 4 columns using a asp web control..ex: Gridview

Comment: this is a weird question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It technically is a repeater function but if I get the hardcoded function... I can make the code to make it flexible.  I got it to work.  I was adding a column to an existing table.  This is what I did...

```
for int i=0; i<ds.tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    ds.tables[0].Rows[i]["Count"] = "4";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You add data to rows - so:

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable table = ds.Tables.Add();
    table.Columns.Add("Count", typeof(int));
    table.Rows.Add(4);
```

However, there are probably easier options; a `DataSet` seems **massively** overkill to bind a single value.